# Clicking back button after a Fragment transaction using addToBackStack does nothing

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I want to be able to reverse a `replace` `FragmentTransaction` by using `addToBackStack()`:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();         
Fragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();     
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, scheduleFragment, "scheduleFragment");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("scheduleFragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but after that, clicking the back button does nothing.

From the doc and it's supposed to reverse the transaction.

What am I missing?

Comment: The [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) (see "Implement Back Navigation for Fragments") says to use `.add` instead of `.replace`.
Check the answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack
but I guess `.replace` is not fully supported while `.add` seems to work correctly.

Comment: @Abel Paz' answer below is the right fix for the issue with `.replace`

Answer (score 25):

The right way to do this is using `onBackPressed()` method to catch that back event in your app, and then "pop" the backStack with `popBackStack()`. For example:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Catch back action and pops from backstack
    // (if you called previously to addToBackStack() in your transaction)
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    // Default action on back pressed
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

PD: Sorry for the delay answering, but I just saw your question. Hope it helps!

Comment: Then why the hell, in Android documentation, they communicated the wrong way. :(

Comment: I don't think this logic is necessary.  App will function exactly the same if you use `addToBackStack`.

Comment: Contrary to the way all the doco seems to point to the usage of these constructs, I too am only able to get this working as intended w/ the addition of this code in `OnBackPressed` :/

Comment: Furthermore, it appears this means this part of the Android doco is flat out wrong http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments - "When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action (such as removing a fragment if the transaction added it)."

Comment: if you have overridden onBackPressed() in your activity FragmentTransaction won't work out of the box. Hence, will be checking for the backstack count and popping the backstack manually.

Answer (score 4):

Try `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`
The parameter for `addToBackStack()` is an optional name for the back state, you do not use the tag in the `replace()` method which is just an optional tag for the fragment. 
You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).

Comment: Yes you can keep the tag for referencing the fragment, but does using `addToBackStack(null)` work? What happens if you use this?

Comment: I haven't tried because it does not make sense to me. So I implemented my own `Fragment` stack (see my answer).

Comment: Your answer works but I believe it is unnecessary. When you use `addToBackStack()` you do not pass the fragment or its tag, you pass the name of the stack for it to be added to. When you look at the documentation it says "name An optional name for this back stack state, or null" where name is the string parameter. I think that you could just use `addToBackStack(null)`, it should at least be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

I's been a while but I hope this will help someone.

`fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` won't work if you are extending `AppCompatActivity`. It works well in `Activity`. I couldn't find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my own `Fragment` stack:

```
public Fragment addFragmentToStack(Fragment fragment){
    if(MyApplication.fragmentStack.size()>20){
        MyApplication.fragmentStack.remove(0);
    }
    return MyApplication.fragmentStack.push(fragment);
}   

public void onBackPressed() {
        if (MyApplication.fragmentStack.size() > 0) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_container, MyApplication.fragmentStack.pop());
            ft.commit();
        }
        else{
            finish();
        }
}
```