# Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the main difference between calling these methods:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(name);
fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
```

What does it mean to replace an already existing fragment, and adding a fragment to the activity state, and adding an activity to the back stack?

Secondly, with `findFragmentByTag()`, does this search for tag added by the `add()`/`replace()` method or the `addToBackStack()` method?

Answer (score 377, accepted):

**1)** `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str);`

*Description* - Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

**2)** `fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

*Description* - Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

**3)** `fragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

*Description* - Add a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.

> What does it mean to replace an already existing fragment, and adding
>   a fragment to the activity state and adding an activity to the back
>   stack ?

There is a stack in which all the activities in the running state are kept. Fragments belong to the activity. So you can add them to embed them in a activity.

You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. This is essentially useful when you have defined your fragment container at different layouts. You just need to replace with any other fragment in any layout.

When you navigate to the current layout, you have the id of that container to replace it with the fragment you want.

You can also go back to the previous fragment in the backStack with the `popBackStack()` method. For that you need to add that fragment in the stack using `addToBackStack()` and then `commit()` to reflect. This is in reverse order with the current on top.

> findFragmentByTag does this search for tag added by the add/replace
>   method or the addToBackStack method ?

If depends upon how you added the tag. It then just finds a fragment by its tag that you defined before either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction.

References: [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: So, can i add fragment by replace method at the beginning activity initiated?

Comment: (No fragment was added before)

Comment: Can a fragment container contains more than one fragment, If yes than how replace() method will behave. WIll it replace all the frgaments in that container or android api have a method that accept three arguments, i.e. frgamentContainer, new fragment and with whom to replace.

Comment: @ved No, it will replace all fragments currently existing in the container with the current one.

Answer (score 400):

One more important difference between `add` and `replace` is this:

`replace` removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment. This means when you press back button the fragment that got replaced will be created with its `onCreateView` being invoked. Whereas `add` retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is pressed `onCreateView` is not called for the existing fragment(the fragment which was there before new fragment was added).

In terms of fragment's life cycle events  `onPause`, `onResume`, `onCreateView` and other life cycle events will be invoked in case of `replace` but they wont be invoked in case of `add`.

**Edit**: One should be careful if she is using some kind of event bus library like [Greenrobot's Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and reusing the same fragment to stack the fragment on top of other via  `add`. In this scenario, even though you follow the best practice and register the event bus in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause`, event bus would still be active in each instance of the added fragment as `add` fragment wont call either of these fragment life cycle methods. As a result event bus listener in each active instance of the fragment would process the same event which may not be what you want.

Comment: I think one approach could be to process the event in the top most fragment and call cancelEventDelivery() after processing is complete. You can find more about the cancelEventDelivery() methods here https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md#cancelling-event-delivery

Comment: +1 from me. Very important to know that replacing current fragment with new fragment, means that previous fragment will be recreated to get it back when popping back from fragment stack.

Comment: onPause, onResume is tightly associated to Host Activity. And they didn't call when replacing fragment.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you are using EventBus you can add the fragment with Tag, and pass from fragment that tag to the event, and check anyway, all eventbus will be called, you just specify which one should execute

Comment: You must mention that you are calling addToBackStack() along with add() or replace() methods.

Comment: so basically, use `replace` instead of `add` for a fragment that fills its container

Comment: This is super relevant even today, as we use menuProviders. MenuProviders that need to follow its Fragment's lifecycle must have a fragment whose transaction was `replace`.

Answer (score 184):

Here is a picture that shows the difference between `add()` and `replace()`

[image]

So `add()` method keeps on adding fragments **on top of** the previous fragment in FragmentContainer.

While `replace()` methods **clears all** the previous Fragment from Containers and then add it in FragmentContainer.

What is addToBackStack

`addtoBackStack` method can be used with add() and replace methods. It serves a different purpose in Fragment API.

What is the purpose?

Fragment API unlike Activity API does not come with **Back Button navigation** by default. If you want to go back to the previous Fragment then the we use addToBackStack() method in Fragment. Let's understand both

**Case 1:**

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "TAG")
            .addToBackStack("TAG")
            .commit();
```

[image]

**Case 2:**

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "TAG")
            .commit();
```

[image]

Comment: pictures speak more than words.

Comment: what happen If in case 1  and 2 we use "replace" in the place of "add" ??

Answer (score 177):

Example an activity have 2 fragments and we use `FragmentManager` to replace/add with `addToBackstack` each fragment to a layout in activity

**Use replace**

*Go Fragment1*

```
Fragment1: onAttach
Fragment1: onCreate
Fragment1: onCreateView
Fragment1: onActivityCreated
Fragment1: onStart
Fragment1: onResume
```

*Go Fragment2*

```
Fragment2: onAttach
Fragment2: onCreate
Fragment1: onPause
Fragment1: onStop
Fragment1: onDestroyView
Fragment2: onCreateView
Fragment2: onActivityCreated
Fragment2: onStart
Fragment2: onResume
```

*Pop Fragment2*

```
Fragment2: onPause
Fragment2: onStop
Fragment2: onDestroyView
Fragment2: onDestroy
Fragment2: onDetach
Fragment1: onCreateView
Fragment1: onStart
Fragment1: onResume
```

*Pop Fragment1*

```
Fragment1: onPause
Fragment1: onStop
Fragment1: onDestroyView
Fragment1: onDestroy
Fragment1: onDetach
```

**Use add**

*Go Fragment1*

```
Fragment1: onAttach
Fragment1: onCreate
Fragment1: onCreateView
Fragment1: onActivityCreated
Fragment1: onStart
Fragment1: onResume
```

*Go Fragment2*

```
Fragment2: onAttach
Fragment2: onCreate
Fragment2: onCreateView
Fragment2: onActivityCreated
Fragment2: onStart
Fragment2: onResume
```

*Pop Fragment2*

```
Fragment2: onPause
Fragment2: onStop
Fragment2: onDestroyView
Fragment2: onDestroy
Fragment2: onDetach
```

*Pop Fragment1*

```
Fragment1: onPause
Fragment1: onStop
Fragment1: onDestroyView
Fragment1: onDestroy
Fragment1: onDetach
```

[Sample project](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidFragmentAddVsReplace.git)

Comment: wasn't  `onPause()` supposed to be called before `onStop()` on every **Pop** action ?

Comment: excellent answer to differentiate between 'add()' and 'replace()', though missing about addToBackStack(). Upvote

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I believe he demonstrated difference between add and replace with addToBackStack on both cases.

Comment: This is a way better answer other than just the theory

Comment: easy to remember than theory

Answer (score 62):

Although it is an old question already answered, maybe those next examples can complement the accepted answer and they can be useful for some new programmers in Android as I am.

**Option 1 - "addToBackStack()" is never used**

*Case 1A - adding, removing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
add Fragment C :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
remove Fragment C :     onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Fragment B is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               App is closed, nothing is visible
```

*Case 1B - adding, replacing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
(replace Fragment C)    
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()
Fragment C :        onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()
Fragment C :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               App is closed, nothing is visible
```

**Option 2 - "addToBackStack()" is always used**

*Case 2A - adding, removing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
add Fragment C :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
remove Fragment C :     onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView()                              Fragment B is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()                   Fragment C is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Fragment B is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Fragment A is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()                              App is closed, nothing is visible
```

*Case 2B - adding, replacing, removing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
(replace Fragment C)    
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView()  
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() 
Fragment C :        onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
remove Fragment C :     onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView()                              Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()                   Fragment C is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               
Fragment A :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()   
Fragment B :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()                   Fragment B is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Fragment A is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()                              App is closed, nothing is visible
```

**Option 3 - "addToBackStack()" is not used always** (in the below examples, w/o indicates that it is not used)

*Case 3A - adding, removing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B w/o:     onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
add Fragment C w/o:     onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
remove Fragment C :     onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Fragment B is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()                              App is closed, nothing is visible
```

*Case 3B - adding, replacing, removing, and clicking Back button*

```
Activity :      onCreate() - onStart() - onResume()                             Activity is visible
add Fragment A :    onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment A is visible
add Fragment B w/o:     onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment B is visible
(replace Fragment C)    
Fragment B :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()   
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() 
Fragment C :        onAttach() - onCreate() - onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()     Fragment C is visible
remove Fragment C :     onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView()                              Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()                   Fragment C is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment C :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               
Fragment A :        onCreateView() - onActivityCreated() - onStart() - onResume()                   Fragment A is visible
(Back button clicked)
Fragment A :        onPause() - onStop() - onDestroyView() - onDestroy() - onDetach()               Activity is visible
(Back button clicked)
Activity :      onPause() - onStop() - onDestroy()                              App is closed, nothing is visible
```

Comment: So can we say that while working with fragments back button works in a similar fashion to the FragmentManager.popBackStack() function?

Answer (score 38):

Basic difference between `add()` and `replace()` can be described as:

- `add()` is used for simply adding a fragment to some root element.
- `replace()` behaves similarly but at first it removes previous fragments and then adds next fragment.

We can see the exact difference when we use `addToBackStack()` together with `add()` or `replace()`.

When we press back button after in case of `add()`... onCreateView is never called, but in case of `replace()`, when we press back button ... oncreateView is called every time.

Comment: So is add() results in more burden in terms of android memory,  since the previous fragment's view is not destroyed?

Comment: @Derekyy Yes, I think so.

Comment: @Derekyy it depends on use case. If there is a high chances that user will navigate to previous screen then I think replace will have more burden on memory

Answer (score 7):

**Important thing to be noticed:**

Difference between Replace and Replace with backstack is whenever we use only replace then the fragment is destroyed ( ondestroy() is called ) and when we use replace with backstack then fragments onDestroy() is not called ( i.e when back button is pressed fragment is invoked with its onCreateView())

Comment: that's why people using `fragment.getViewLifeCycle()` in such cases:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states

Answer (score 2):

**When We Add First Fragment --> Second Fragment using add() method**

```
 btn_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click First 
Fragment",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
//                        .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
```

**When we use add() in fragment**

```
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onAttach
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onCreate
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onCreateView
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onActivityCreated
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onStart
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onResume
```

**When we use replace() in fragment**

**going to first fragment to second fragment in  First -->Second using replace() method**

```
 btn_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click First Fragment",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                        .add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });

E/Keshav SecondFragment: onAttach
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onCreate

E/Keshav FirstFragment: onPause -------------------------- FirstFragment
E/Keshav FirstFragment: onStop --------------------------- FirstFragment
E/Keshav FirstFragment: onDestroyView -------------------- FirstFragment

E/Keshav SecondFragment: onCreateView
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onActivityCreated
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onStart
E/Keshav SecondFragment: onResume
```

In case of Replace First Fragment these method is extra called ( onPause,onStop,onDestroyView  is extra called )

**E/Keshav FirstFragment: onPause**

**E/Keshav FirstFragment: onStop**

**E/Keshav FirstFragment: onDestroyView**

Answer (score 0):

The FragmentManger's function add and replace can be described as these
1. add means it will add the fragment in the fragment back stack and it will show at given frame you are providing
like

`getFragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(R.id.contentframe,Fragment1.newInstance(),null)`

2.replace means that you are replacing the fragment with another fragment at the given frame

`getFragmentManager.beginTransaction.replace(R.id.contentframe,Fragment1.newInstance(),null)`

The Main utility between the two is that when you are back stacking the replace will refresh the fragment but add will not refresh previous fragment.