# Adding multiple fragments to the same containerView and then handling back pressed: Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have a container view in an activity to which I have added FragmentA and added it to the backStack. Now, based on some button click I want FragmentA to be replaced in the same container view with FragmentB. But I want to make sure that FragmentA comes back to the UI when back is pressed from FragmentB.

I am confused and so could someone please explain how to handle the above scenario.

Thanks. 
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

Add the Fragment's to backstack. `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Quoting docs

> By calling addToBackStack(), the replace transaction is saved to the
>   back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the
>   previous fragment by pressing the Back button.

More info @ **Performing Fragment Transactions** in

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You can check this further

[Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

Comment: that is what i did but it didnt seem to work. Ok let me try again. Btw, how is replace different from detach/attach?

Comment: @Sunny read the docs and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Fragment`B to the backstack as well on the `FragmentTransaction` that replaces `Fragment`A with `Fragment`B

Comment: ok great it finally worked. one add on question though...when i press back key it comes back to prev fragment (A) but when i press back on the action bar the whole activity disappers

Comment: That is the correct behavior if the `Activity` in question is the only `Activity` left on the `Activity` backstack. Check this link regarding [Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)