# Basic difference between add() and replace() method of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do `Fragment`'s replace and add methods work differently, and is there any real life scenario where we would need these methods for specific purposes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The important difference is:

`replace` removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment..

but `add` retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is pressed `onCreateView()` is not called for the existing fragment(the fragment which was there before new fragment was added).

For more information just visit [this conversation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

Comment: do u mean that existing fragment will be in paused state ?

Answer (score 4):

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

**Description** - It replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling `remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments given here.

```
fragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

**Description** - It add a fragment to the activity state. This fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.

Please visit below official android developer link for more details about fragments... 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html