# Save RecyclerView State inside Fragment in ViewPager created inside another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment`

```
public class FragmentPager extends BaseFragment {

    @Bind(R.id.viewpager)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Bind(R.id.detail_tabs)
    TabLayout detailTabs;

    private Activity mActivity;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        viewPager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
        detailTabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

I am already using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to manage my fragments in ViewPager. Each Fragment has a `RecyclerView`. On clicking each item of the `RecyclerView` I am replacing the `FragmentPager` with `FragmentDetail`. When I navigate back to the `FragmentPager`, the  `RecyclerView` starts from the beginning instead of position scrolled.

Comment: are you using fragment transactions to replace the fragment `FragmentPager`?

Comment: @driIon-blakqori Is there any other way?

Comment: you can use `add()` instead of `replace()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you change your fragment with fragmentTransaction replace method. You need to do it with fragmentTransaction add method. See the below

[Basic difference between add() and replace() method of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466302/basic-difference-between-add-and-replace-method-of-fragment)

Comment: I don't want to add it but instead, replace it. And Even if I do my Shared Element Transition won't work.