# Fragment not displayed after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation

I have one activity, `ActivityA`, and 3 fragments, `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, and `FragmentC`.

To add FragmentA, I use `replace`, where `fragment` is a new instance of `FragmentA`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_layout_fragment, fragment)
        .commit();
```

In the `onCreate` method of ActivityA, I do a check for `FragmentA` creation:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = FragmentA.newInstance();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_layout_fragment, fragmentA)
            .commit();
}
```

To add `FragmentB` and `FragmentC`, I use `add` and `addToBackStack`, where `fragment` is either a new instance of `FragmentB` or `FragmentC`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.frame_layout_fragment, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

I press the back button while on `FragmentC`, it shows `FragmentB`, and pressing the back button while on `FragmentB` shows `FragmentA`, as expected. While I was on `FragmentC`, I rotate the device, and `FragmentC` still shows, as expected.

However, when I navigate from `FragmentC` to `FragmentA` using the 2 presses of the back button, then rotate the device twice, portrait -> landscape -> portrait, add `FragmentB`, add `FragmentC`, then I rotate the device once, I expected `FragmentC` to show, but instead `FragmentB` shows. When I press the back button once, nothing happens. When I press it again, it navigates back to `FragmentA`. It seems like `FragmentC` is present in the back stack, but for some reason its not visible.

Why is `FragmentC` not visible in this scenario?

Comment: did any one solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer to another question is your answer too: [Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

It says:

> One more importance difference between add and replace is: replace
>   removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment. This means when
>   you press back button the fragment that got replaced will be created
>   with its onCreateView being invoked. Whereas add retains the existing
>   fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be
>   active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is
>   pressed onCreateView is not called for the existing fragment(the
>   fragment which was there before new fragment was added). In terms of
>   fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView and other
>   life cycle events will be invoked in case of replace but they wont be
>   invoked in case of add.

Comment: Rotating the device calls onCreateView for every fragment in my case. FragmentC is not showing even though onCreateView was called.