# Which lifecycle methods are called when a fragment is popped off backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **FragmentA** and **FragmentB**. 
I added **FragmentA** to an Activity using the `add` (not replace) fragment transaction. A button in **FragmentA** makes a callback to it's Activity  which then makes an `add` fragment transaction to add **FragmentB**.

I update the title of the ActionBar with the value of a variable (which is fetched online) in **FragmentA** and **FragmentB**.

After the fragment transactions I outlined above, if I'm in **FragmentB** and I press the back button (now I'm in **FragmentA**), the title of the   ActionBar is still that of **FragmentB**.

So I wanted to know which lifecycle methods are called on **FragmentA** when I'm coming from **FragmentB** so I can update the Actionbar from there.

Comment: You should do the setting of the title in `onCreateView` of the respective `Fragment`. So in your `FragmentA`, set title of the `ActionBar` to whatever you desire, and do the same in `FragmentB`'s `onCreateView` method. Let me know if this gives the behavior you desire.

Comment: It won't work. `onCreatView` won't be called. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18634207/6215423

Comment: @Roseyk try with onViewCreated method.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a method that is called when backstack is popped, but what you can do is overwrite onBackPressed in your Activity class that contains the fragments, call fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate. This method returns a boolean, if it's true, then you went from fragmentB to fragmentA (or to any other previous fragment). You are in your activity class, so you can update your ActionBar anyway you'd like.
One more thing, if fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate is true, don't call super.onBackPressed()!!!

Answer (score -2):

`onStart()` method is clearly the adapted one. When comming from backstack, it will always be called.