# How to remove Fragment transactions in middle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 5 fragments(say A, B, C, D, E) and one activity with a container.
Whenever i want to add a fragment to a container I'll be using the following code.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainerRL, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

Let's say i added Fragment A.
Upon some action in A, I added fragment B.
Upon some action in B, I added fragment C.
Upon some action in C, I added fragment D.
Upon some action in D, I added fragment E.

Now my stack should be as follows.
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Now upon some action in Fragment E, I need to remove fragments D, C, B so that when user click back, he should directly see Fragment A.

I tried using following code.

```
public void removeScreen(@NonNull String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove(fragment);
        trans.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Upon some action in Fragment E, I called the above function with Tags of Fragment D, C, B(Tags are same as the one that i used for fragment transaction).

Now when i click back button fragment D is becoming visible but i was expecting fragment A.

It would be very helpful if somebody points out where am i going wrong.

Comment: When user clicks the back button then you can use 'fragmentManager.popBackStack()' to remove E, D, C, B fragments.

Comment: If i do fragmentManager.popBackStack(), then Fragment E will be removed first. But i want to retain Fragment E and remove Fragments B,C,D which are in background..

Comment: hi, do you fix the issue, in my case, the fragment is overlapped.

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach exactly the same behavior that you've described, you can do it by this way:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

This will clear all backstack until the bottom of stack will be reached.

Comment: What if my requirement is to remove B, C fragments after some action in fragment E without going back to A immediately? After it I need to go to F and G fragments and then back from fragment F to fragment A by a multiple pressing of "back" key and I have to ignore B and C fragments completely on this way. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `DialogFragment` for this reason and pop them using interface callbacks and `dismiss()` function inside them. This is the easiest and quick way to implement what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think  your problem occur here :

replace :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainerRL, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

to：

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainContainerRL, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

when you add your fragment to container,tou just add it ,if use"replace" method,you romove it from activirty's fagment manager,it case your "removeScreen" method did not work

Comment: I want to use replace otherwise all fragments added will be kept in memory. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Comment: In most cases `add` is a bad choice. Use `remove` wherever it is possible.