# android fragment add vs replace in terms of memory

Tags: android, android-fragments

if I have just one fragment on the page, calling replace and remove/add is basically the same.

I can't seem to find an article talking the cons and pros between those 2 approaches. I'm more worry about the performance and also if add will create memory leak because the fragment isn't going through its lifecycle to release the views and vars within the fragment.

can someone please explain the pros and cons? Thanks!

Comment: did you try this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634392/3678308

Comment: @Java coder yes, but i cant find the answer im looking for