# How to go back to last activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

How is it possible to go back to the last `Activity` one has been in from a `Fragment`? Let's assume we've `Activity` A and `Fragment` A. I launch `Fragment` A from `Activity` A, and now I want to go back to `Fragment` A. When I press on the back button on my phone it closes the app.

I launch the fragment by using the `FragmentManager`:

```
Fragment fragment = new Kontakt();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.kontaktfrag, fragment)
                    .commit();
```

Is the solution; `popBackStackImmediate()` or `addToBackStack()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18634392/3498931 -- this will help, if you had tried the option by yourself you would know better ..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try `addToBackStack` when adding your fragment.
then you need to override your `onBackPressed` function of your activity, for example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I tried myself and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
 getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.addToBackStack("")
.commit();
```

or just add .addToBackStack("")  before .commit();

here is the code in your case,

```
 Fragment fragment = new Kontakt();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.kontaktfrag, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("")
                .commit();
```

Comment: Instead of `add` ?