# Return from fragment C to fragment A pressing back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I have a fragments, for example A -> B -> C. When I'm in the fragment C, and press the back button I need to get on a fragment A. That is, fragment B is not necessary to add to backStack. Here is the code which implements the transition between fragments.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
fragment.getArguments().putAll(args);

transaction.replace(idContainer, fragment, tag);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

At the opening of the fragment C, I don't use *transaction.addToBackStack(null);*

And now I have the following problem. From the fragment С I click the back button and enters the fragment A, but two layers of fragments are superimposed on each other.

[Like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMvrz.png)

Comment: Add all the fragments in backstack and then iterate for loop till first fragment

Comment: are you using viewpager?

Comment: Maybe you want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

Answer (score 1):

Transition from A to B

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new BFragment(), "BFragment").addToBackStack("A_TO_B").commit();
```

Transition from B to C

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new CFragment(), "CFragment").addToBackStack("B_TO_C").commit();
```

Override Activity's onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed();
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CFragment") != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("A_TO_B",
    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
} else {
       super.onBackPressed();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in Fragment_C To go back to Fragment_A on Back press button from fragment_C

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){


                Fragment_A fragment = null;
                fragment = new Fragment_A();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you call `Transaction.addToBackStack(null)`, your `Fragment` added to backstack, so you shouldn't call when you don't want to add your fragment to backstack.

**What you should do**

When you are replacing your `Fragment-A` with `Fragment-B` you should not call `Transaction.addToBackStack(null)`, but when you replace `Fragment-B` with `Fragment-C` you should call `Transaction.addToBackStack(null)`.

Doing this your `Fragment-A` and `Fragment-C` will be backstacked but `Fragment-B` will not, now when you press the back button you will have `Fragment-A`.