# Why a fragment from the backstack gets triggered when adding a new fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

Something strange is happening..!

So I have an activity with TextView in the center of the toolbar acting as toolbar title, once the activity gets launched, I commit the MainFragment or let's name it `Fragment (A)`.

- Inside Fragment (A), I replace it with Fragment (B) when a button
  gets clicked.
- Inside Fragment (B), I replace it with Fragment (C)
  when a button gets clicked.

so in each fragment I access the activity's toolbar text view and change it accordingly using this:

```
TextView title = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.titleText);
  title.setText("Some title");
```

And it works fine in Fragments (A) & (B), but in (C) it shows the title of Fragment (A)??
I even printed a log inside the onCreateView of each fragment and this is what showed up..!

the last two logs showed at the same time..!?

`I/MY_TEST: onCreateView:   of Fragment (A) 
I/MY_TEST: onCreateView:   of Fragment (B)
I/MY_TEST: onCreateView:   of Fragment (C)
I/MY_TEST: onCreateView:   of Fragment (A)`

---

**Update**

Here's the full click listener

```
orderDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
                Fragment fragment = new Teacher_Bar_Fragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("index", 1); // I use this to show or hide views
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you post the full `onClickListeners` for the button clicks on these fragments?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Comment: @IshitaSinha check the update

Comment: Something as strange as this needs the full code to understand, please post the code of activity, xml, ...