# Difference between add vs addToBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have read this [Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack). I have a confusion that If I add multiple fragments like below then If I press back button from fragment2 then will fragment1 will open ? If so then what is the use of `addToBackStack` as `add` already maintaining a stack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llContainer, fragment1, "fragment_one");

Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llContainer, fragment2, "fragment_two");

ft.commit();
```

Comment: No. The app will finish if you did not put `addToBackStack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you call multiple times **add** method on [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)) like this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llContainer, fragment1, "fragment_one");

Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llContainer, fragment2, "fragment_two");

ft.commit();
```

then both the fragments that been added to FragmentTransaction will be shown as overlapping.

[image]

Now clicking back will close the application. It won't start the previous fragment.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add method will not add your Fragment in BackStack. You need to verify once again. 
While looking into code of `addToBackStack`

```
@Override
public FragmentTransaction addToBackStack(String name) {
    if (!mAllowAddToBackStack) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "This FragmentTransaction is not allowed to be added to the back stack.");
    }
    mAddToBackStack = true;
    mName = name;
    return this;
}
```

Flag `mAddToBackStack = true;` enabled which value is `false` by default. And this is the flag which is being used to add fragment into backstack. Have a look into below methods calls

```
@Override
public int commit() {
    return commitInternal(false);
}

int commitInternal(boolean allowStateLoss) {
    ......
    if (mAddToBackStack) {
        mIndex = mManager.allocBackStackIndex(this);
    } else {
        mIndex = -1;
    }
    .....
}
```

So what you observed is not correct. Something you are missing