# Which best way for using multiple Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two fragments as `SignInFragment` and `SignUpFragment`. First `MainActivity` calls `SignInFragment` with this code.

```
//MainActivity
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    signInFragment = new SignInFragment();
    signUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_holder,signInFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

How can I call `SignUpFragment` after clicking a sign-up button in `SignInFragment`. I have got a reference to the button:

```
//SignInFragment    
Button buttonSignUp = view.findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up);
```

Comment: I suggest you become very familiar with [the Official Android documentation](https://d.android.com). You should start by checking out the docs about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions). A google search will also turn up lots of information for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `onClick` for the **signup** button first.

and place this code inside

```
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_holder, signInFragment);
              fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and as [sudhanshu-vohra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6726650/sudhanshu-vohra) said you must **replace** it not **add** it to the `frame_holder`.

Answer (score 0):

Override their respective **onClick()** methods to respond to click events on the Buttons and write the code to **replace** the fragments in the following manner:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.button_sign_up:
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_holder, signInFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Note: You need to **replace** the fragment and not **add** the fragment when adding any fragment second time(or any consecutive time) because add will simply overlay the other fragment on the first fragment. For more information, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack).