# Replace fragment clears all Edittext Value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

Inside `Select Case` I used this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_entry, new fragment_1())
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

to switch between fragments, but I have a problem with it. The fragment contains `EditText` with a pre-selected values. When I go to `fragment_2` and then return to `fragment_1` the selected value on my `EditText` is gone. How can I make the value stay?

Comment: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.frame_entry, new fragment_1())
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();

Comment: Because you are replacing the fragment each time with the new object.

Comment: i use the `.add` but when i switch between `fragments` 1 and 2 combines

Comment: @MahavirJain thats true because i dont know how to maintain add

Comment: it looks like fragment1 and 2 combines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Answer (score 0):

This will probably [Fragment Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Example) help.

Override onSaveInstanceState like this.

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}
```

Then you can use it later

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore last state for checked position.
    mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
 }
}
```

OnActivityCreated is invoked after fragment returns from back stack.

Comment: can you please elaborate? how can I implement this?

Comment: paste the following function in your activity or fragment and whenever you want to switch between fragments call this function

Comment: i figured it out currently testing

Comment: try to save the value of edittext when before fragment transaction occurs and then retrieve when the same fragment is called.

Comment: can you guide me on how to do that? maybe a short example

Comment: Im getting this error `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.app.Fragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'`

Comment: remove import android.app.Fragment