# fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() does not decrease when removing fragment from manager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

The correct behavior I'd like to have is:

```
Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment A
```

What I currently do:

1. When I want to go back from B to A, I use `popBackStack()` still here
   everything goes well.
2. When I want to go from B to C I remove B and
   add C. (number of Fragments 2, number of backStackEntryCount 3, same for replace).
3. When I want to go back from C to A, I can use
   `popBackStack()` but the BackStackEntryCount will still contain the
   entry for B.

I really need the `backStackEntryCount` to be the same as the fragments contained in the manager.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
        Fragment fragment1 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("NavigationFragment_");
    if (fragment1 != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .remove(fragment1)
                .commit();

    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(backstack)
            .setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            //.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NavigationFragment_.class.getSimpleName()))
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commit();
```

I have been searching for a solution for a while without results, so please do not mark this a duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: What does it mean? :')

Comment: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok, I am doing one now

Comment: If you want to replace the fragment in a container you should use `replace` instead of `remove` and `add`. 
Good answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634392/1729054

Comment: @LucaCorradi As I wrote, it does not have any effect and fix to my problem even because it is the same according to the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#replace

Comment: @m0skit0 this is the logic:https://github.com/JonathanImperato/test/tree/master , sorry for the late answer

Comment: SSCCE, here, is known as MCVE: [mcve].

Comment: @KlingKlang Right, but that SO post lacks a very important point: "By identifying more clearly where the problem occurs, you have just made an important step toward solving it. The process that highlights where a problem originates can, in itself, help to solve it. You might look more closely at the part cut out, and in doing so, spot the problem. Even if you cannot see why the problem occurs, you have still made an important step: identifying (at least part) of the code involved".

Comment: @JonathanI `BaseFragment#showFragment` always tries to remove `FragmentB`.

Comment: @m0skit0 I usually make a control, if FragmentB does not exist in the fragment manager then nothing will be removed, I forgot to add it, fixing it now in the project sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FragmentManager's back stack is only updated in two cases:

1. You commit a FragmentTransaction using `addToBackStack()`
2. You call `popBackStack()`

No other operation affects the back stack - additional FragmentTransactions without `addToBackStack()` only change the current state and do not affect what happens when you call `popBackStack()`, etc.

If you want your stack to go from `A` to `A -> B`, you'd use a FragmentTransaction with `addToBackStack` (and generally, a `replace` operation):

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentB)
    .addToBackStack("b")
    .commit();
```

Then, you want your back stack to `A -> B` to `A -> C`, you'd need to do two operations:

```
// First pop B
fragmentManager.popBackStack("b", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
// Then addToBackStack C
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentC)
    .addToBackStack("c")
    .commit();
```

This ensures that your `FragmentB` is removed from the stack before adding `FragmentC` to the back stack.

Similarly, if you want to then remove `FragmentC` and go back to `FragmentA`, you'd just pop it from the back stack:

```
// Pop C, returning back to A
fragmentManager.popBackStack("c", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Note: it is never a good idea to mix back stack FragmentTransactions and regular FragmentTransactions in the same FragmentManager since `popBackStack()` does not take into account the current state of the `FragmentManager`, but instead just blindly reverses the FragmentTransaction on the back stack (i.e., the last FragmentTransaction with `addToBackStack()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you come here because you call popBackStack() but getBackStackEntryCount() doesn't seem to update, then you might want to try popBackStackImmediate() instead.

popBackStack() is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.

Comment: It is the same, for what I asked it does not make any difference.