# how to restore last opened fragment inside an activity after getting back from another actvivty

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

I'm using multiple fragments inside an activity like this flow: Fragment A has a list on it's item click Fragment B opens and it also has a list opens Fragment C which has a list Open another Activity , The problem is when I go back from the other Activity I found Fragment A is opened, How I restore the last Fragment C when go back from the other activity?

here is the code of replacing Fragment inside my activity

```
 protected void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    String TAG = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_home, fragment, TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384899/7555998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**replace** removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment. This means when you press back button the fragment that got replaced will be created with its onCreateView being invoked. Whereas **add** retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active.

Use add instead of replace

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_home, fragment, TAG);
```

I had the same issue solved using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

instead of,

```
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
```

Hope Your problem will solve.