# Move from one Fragment inside Activity to another Fragment inside Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have **Activity A** with **Fragment A.1**, and I also have **Activity B** with **Fragment B.1**.

What I want to ask is, how do I move directly from **Fragment A.1** to **Fragment B.1**?

I know to move from **Fragment A.1** to **Activity B**, is by:

```
Intent i = new Intent (getActivity (), MainActivity.class);                     
startActivity (i);                     
getActivity ().finish();
```

But how to move straight to **Fragment B.1**?
Each **Activity A** and **Activity B** has a different `<FrameLayout>` for Fragment replacement

> UPDATE 1.0

I've tried my own way and also the way @cewaphi answered with code like this,

In **Activity A**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(TransactionDone.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("immediatelyTransactionToFragment", true);
startActivity(i);
finishAffinity();
```

In **Activity B**:

```
boolean shouldTransitionToFragment = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("immediatelyTransationToFragment", true);
if (shouldTransitionToFragment) {
Fragment fragment = new Wallet();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment);
transaction.commit();
Log.d("DEBUGGING REDIRECT", "Go to Fragment B.1");
}
```

The log "*Go to Fragment B.1*" was created but the transaction doesn't work

Comment: So here is the first thing. Do you want activity B to launch with fragment B.1 while moving from your Activity A? If so I do not sure how to achieve, because to display your fragment B.1 UI, you must launch it inside any activity. So for your question, I need little clarification, 1-> Does your priority to just launch fragment B.1 or launch it with inside Activity B1?

Comment: @KP I'm assuming I'm in Fragment A.1 in Activity A, and yes I want to be able to move to Fragment B.1 in Activity B. My reason isn't just launching Fragment B.1, because in Fragment B.1 there are a lot of operations So maybe I need to not just launch?

Comment: you can pass a variable with intent if intent has that extra in it just load the fragment in second activity

Comment: if you want it, you must call your activity B which holds your Fragment B.1. There is no way you can directly call fragment as standalone according to my knowledge. You can do call Activity B and make sure to do your Fragment B.1 transaction in ActivtyB in oncCreate() using fragment transactions. In your use case easy solution to use fragment transaction with single activity and replace fragment inside ActivityA.

Comment: @KP But... Fragment B.1 is now only accessible by click trigger in Activity B, it doesn't trigger automatically

Comment: @kelvin so I have to make logic in Activity B, if there is a value of 'example-value' then load Fragment B.1?

Comment: Yes . also why dont you replace Fragment A1 with fragment B1 inside Activity A .

Comment: so I am assuming your Activity B does have some views and also fragment tag? Clicking on views you want to hide views and display fragments? If you want to Acess Fragment B 1 from Activity B, you must call Activity B from your Activity A.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have multiple activities here? What you want to do becomes much easier when using the single activity approach in your app and especially when you are using the convenience of the [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate)

Comment: @cewaphi Yes I think so. but because this project is being worked on together, my other team worked on using 2 activities because they couldn't load the Webview responsively.

Comment: This problem should be easier to solve, when I only use one Activity which is used by all the Fragments. Thank you friend

Comment: If I may ask, why does another activity make the loading more responsive?

Comment: for your current approach: why do you not put an extra boolean in your intent when starting activity B from fragment A. 1? Then on receiving this boolean inside your activity B you move to fragment B. 1 after your activity has been created.  If not for this boolean from Fragment A1 you only move from activity B with your button click.  Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @cewaphi Yeah right, that's the approach I want. Talking about other Activities makes loading more responsive, these are just words from my team. I just tried before and there was no problem

Answer (score 0):

When using a single activity and e.g. using the navigation component is not an option.
Consider the following:

- In your fragment A.1 when starting the activity store a `Boolean`

  ```
  i.putExtra("immediatelyTransationToFragment", true);
  ```
- In activity B

  ```
  shouldTransitionToFragment = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("immediatelyTransationToFragment"); 
  // after activity was created
  if (shouldTransitionToFragment) {
      // Execute the transition action as you would when pressing the button
  }
  ```

Update 2020/09/07

You are trying to transition to a `Fragment` from your `Activity` like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

The [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) that you should first `add` the fragment to the activity:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Apparently your transition works when you click your button. Are you doing it the same?
But I assume at that time the activity has already been created.
Try once to `add` your fragment instead of `replace`. I don't know how your container is initialised but adding might be the operation you want, I refer to [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684520/13138026) for clarification.

Also consider to perform to call this transaction **after** your activity was created.

Comment: Can this directly trigger Begin Transaction to Fragment B.1? I have tried "If the value of the getStringExtra() result is not empty, then Begin Transaction to Fragment B.1." But it doesn't work. I've written it in onCreate ()

Comment: Can you post the code how you try to transition to the fragment? If you do not have your `if` statement, does the transition (generally) not work?

Comment: To be honest, I am usually not conducting Fragment transactions manually anymore since I have switched to the convenience of the Navigation Component. I will update my answer accordingly for what I have noticed.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, it's just a matter of time when I actually have to migrate using a navigation component. migrating all that current code would be very painful

Comment: By the way replacing `transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment);` with `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);` doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: I already assumed it wouldn't make a difference. How do you do it when you click the button? Does it work when you move after creating the activity (and not during creating it)?