# Fragment Transaction Issue in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have a Fragment A in My app.

From the Fragment A, I am moving to Fragment B.

Note that I am adding the Fragment B on Fragment A (**not replacing the Fragment**.)

Now, When I coming back to Fragment A from Fragment B, I have to call a method of Fragment A and that's Why I am calling that method in life cycle method of Fragment A : in **onResume()**, **onViewCreated()**

But What I noticed by putting log in both the method that these methods are not calling means I am not getting Log in logcat and the method which I have called in these two methods is not executing.

What might be the issue? Thanks.

I am doing as below for your reference:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.e("onResume 1","onResume 1")
    (activity as HomeActivity).updateToolbar(false)
    setLanguageSpecificData()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.e("onViewCreated","onViewCreated")
    setLanguageSpecificData()
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is due to *FragmentA* stay on the screen and the `onPause()` method is not called. Respectively `onResume()` will not be called after deleting the top fragment (*FragmentB*).


When you call `transaction.replace()`, you hide your *FragmentA* and `onPause()` will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The way you mentioned in your question that:

> I am adding the Fragment B on Fragment A (not replacing the Fragment.)

So, There is a difference between what lifecycle methods gets called based on `replace` & `add`.

If you take a look at this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684520/9715339

> In terms of fragment's life cycle events `onPause`, `onResume`,
> `onCreateView` and other life cycle events will be invoked in case of
> `replace` but they wont be invoked in case of `add`

Also, It's tied to activity lifecycle as well.

**Solution:**

Looking at your code you want to update something when current visible fragment changes or in other words `backstack` changes.

For that you can do this in your activity:

```
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
            //when backstack changes get the current fragment & do something with that info
            val frg = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.root_container)
            if (frg is AFragment){
                // do something like updateToolbar(false)
            } else if (frg is BFragment){
                //something else
            }
            Log.d("FrgTest-",frg.toString())
        }
```

In **fragment** you can do `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager` & rest will be fine.

**Read:**

This is just an example for backstack change. If you want to communicate between fragments you can use other ways like `setFragmentResultListener` as well.

This may help: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#kotlin

Comment: The other way is to call the HomeActivity method in which we can call the function of current fragment - fragment which is if added and visible.